# virtual host Redirects Me To Apache default Page Testing 123

Tags: apache, redirect, virtualhost, httpd.conf

I setup Anything in My Server To Connect To A Domain But I have A Problem Httpd Virtual Host Redirect me To Default Apache Page I don't Know Why I Tried Every Solution On Internet But Nothing works.
Here is My File If Anything Else Needed Tell me:

```confing
<VirtualHost *:80>
    documentRoot /var/www/buymeacookie.ir/public_html
    ServerName buymeacookie.ir
    ErrorLog /var/www/buymeacookie.ir/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/buymeacookie.ir/requests.log combined
    #Redirect "/" "https://www.buymeacookie.ir/"
</VirtualHost>
```

I Also Made /var/www/buymeacookie.ir/

and /var/www/buymeacookie.ir/public_html/

and added a  index.html on public_html
But When I Open My URL I get Default Page of Apache.

thank you for reading :D

**EDIT** tree of /var/www is

```
/var/www
├── buymeacookie.ir
│   ├── access.log
│   ├── error_log
│   ├── error.log
│   ├── public_html
│   │   └── index.html
│   └── requests.log
├── cgi-bin
└── html
```

Comment: **1** What is the content of the `index.html` file?  **2** Is there another VirtualHost in your configuration files?  The first one it finds (top to bottom) will be used.  **3** Add a `<Directory>` section for `/var/www/buymeacookie.ir/public_html` to setup permissions on this directory.  **4** Add `LogLevel Debug` and restart.  Look at your logs.  **5** Look at your permissions on the directory.

Comment: @Nic3500 the content of index.html is really simple `<html>
  <head>
    <title>Welcome to Example.com!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Success! The example.com virtual host is working!</h1>
  </body>
</html>
` 2 no other virtual host as far as I know 3 I Added `<Directory>` 4 Where I should Add `LogLevelDebug` 5 They are All 777 permissions

Comment: @Nic3500 Enabled loglevel to warn and got this error`[autoindex:error] [pid 2748] [client 5.74.12.148:4628] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/html/buymeacookie.ir/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.html) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive`

Comment: So add a `DirectoryIndex` directive in your VirtualHost to specify which file to serve by default.

Comment: still getting same error conf file 
`
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName buymeacookie.ir
    ServerAlias www.buymeacookie.ir
    ServerAdmin root@buymeacookie.ir

    DocumentRoot /var/www/buymeacookie.ir/public_html
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    <Directory /var/www/buymeacookie.ir/public_html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
    loglevel warn
    ErrorLog /var/www/buymeacookie.ir/error.log
    CustomLog /var/www/buymeacookie.ir/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
'

Comment: @Nic3500 after some changes you said my IP redirects to my domain folder and domain redirects to empty /var/www/html folder what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how I would configure such a site.  The requirements I figure out from your question:

- domain: [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and example.com
- the files for this domain are in /var/www/example.com/public_html/
- that domain is setup as a VirtualHost, with separated logs for this domain
- IMPORTANT: there are no other VirtualHosts for port 80
- the top directory for Apache will be /opt/apache
- logs will end up in /opt/apache/logs
- default content files are in /opt/apache/htdocs
- /var/www/example.com/public_html/ must be owned by user httpd, group httpd, permissions 750
- if owned by another user, the permissions should be 755, but this is less secure
- modules must be added or removed according to your requirements
- obviously, you must adjust the directories according to your system

---

/opt/apache/conf/httpd.conf

```
ServerRoot "/opt/apache"

Listen 80

LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule slotmem_shm_module modules/mod_slotmem_shm.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so

<IfModule unixd_module>
    User httpd
    Group httpd
</IfModule>

ServerName example.com:80

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "/opt/apache/htdocs"
<Directory "/opt/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
</IfModule>

ErrorLog "logs/error_log"
LogLevel debug
<IfModule log_config_module>
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
    <IfModule logio_module>
        LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
    </IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access_log" combined
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types

    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

Include conf/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Include conf/extra/httpd-default.conf
```

---

/opt/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    ServerAdmin misc@example.com

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog "logs/example.com_error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.com_access_log" combined

    DocumentRoot "/var/www/example.com/public_html/"
    <Directory "/var/www/example.com/public_html/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    DirectoryIndex index.html

</VirtualHost>
```

---

With this setup:

- if you call `http://www.example.com` or `http://example.com`, the files will come from /var/www/example.com/public_html/
- logs under /opt/apache/logs will indicate the start of the httpd
- logs /opt/apache/logs/example.com_*_log will show the transactions and/or errors from your tests

Obviously, this is a starting point, you must adjust for your other requirements.

Comment: i just have `rh` in my opt folder

Comment: The example I showed here will not necessarily be exactly what you have on your system.  Depending on your distribution, Apache httpd is installed in different directories.  Hence when you install httpd on your distribution, look in the packages to know where the files reside for your system.

Answer (score -1):

Line 2 of your .conf file is wrong: must be `DocumentRoot`,  and not `documentRoot`

Comment: Sorry, that is not it.  I just tried on my own Apache, it's ok even if the case is not exact.